# Removing application name in hostname from MuleSoft url's

Tags: rest, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

Question on Mule and how it builds URL's based on Applications..

If we have a application deployed in mule cloud with the name "John", then the URL that it would take to hit an endpoint in that application is:

```
https://{mule-worker-{john}.cloudhub.io:8080/v1/user/details
```

Now, we do not want the application name as part of host name as shown above...Is there any way where {john} can be removed from the host name ?

May be the url could be something like:

```
https://{mule-worker.cloudhub.io:8080/v1/user/details
```

or

```
https://{mule-worker.cloudhub.io:8080/john/v1/user/details
```

Comment: Whatever you name the application will make up part of sub domain in the host name and it also has to be unique. The path can be anything you want it to be though. Just name your application something genericand then look at the HTTP and APIKit modules and REST API principles for structuring your path.

Answer (score 0):

Mule doesn't build domains names like that. [CloudHub](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub) does, the cloud hosting platform of MuleSoft. What you want is not possible. All applications have to published with an unique name to avoid conflicts.

Note that usually you would refer to the application by the DNS name myapp.cloudhub.io. When you use mule-worker-myapp.cloudhub.io it refers directly to the worker where the application is deployed, bypassing the CloudHub load balancer. The differences are explained at the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide#dns-records).

An alternative is to setup a load balancer, custom or [CloudHub Dedicated Load Balancer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-dedicated-load-balancer), to avoid referring to the application name directly. Clients would point to the application name.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is use Dedicated load balancer where you can terminate a custom domain certificate and then you can use your own organisation name (e.g.

```
https://john.com/api/v1/user/details
```